# How to find sequence number of list in python (like line number 1, 2)

Tags: python, list, numbers, line, sequence

I want to find out the line number of the list,

```
def creatList(file):
    try:
        for line in file:
            line=(line.rstrip()).split()
            rawList=[]
            rawList.append(line)
            creatRuleFile(rawList)

    finally:
        print("line(s) printed")

    def creatRuleFile(new):
        print(new)
```

inside creatRuleFile(rawList) function Im tring to display something similarly like this,

```
1. [a,b,c] 
2. [f,h,k] 
3. [b,s,y]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a global variable (bad practice) for the counter, but a better method would be:

```
def creatList(file):
    try:
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            ...
            creatRuleFile(i, rawList)
    ...
```

and

```
def creatRuleFile(i, new):
    print("{0}. {1}".format(i, new))
```

Comment: Thankyou but it gives an error as, in creatList for i,line in file:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: This is not the same as the line I posted. Don't forget the `enumerate`